# HitTest not working as expected

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I am wanting to display a context menu when a user right-clicks on an item within a CListCtrl. My code is as follows:

```
void DatastoreDialog::OnContextMenu(CWnd *pWnd, CPoint pos)
{
    // Find the rectangle around the list control
    CRect rectMainArea;
    m_itemList.GetWindowRect(&rectMainArea);
    // Find out if the user right-clicked the list control
    if( rectMainArea.PtInRect(pos) )
    {
        LVHITTESTINFO hitTestInfo;
        hitTestInfo.pt = pos;
        hitTestInfo.flags = LVHT_ONITEM;
        m_itemList.HitTest(&hitTestInfo);
        if (hitTestInfo.flags & LVHT_NOWHERE)
        {
             // No item was clicked
        }
        else 
        {
            MyContextHandler(hitTestInfo)
        }
    }
}
```

When I actually run the code, regardless of where I click; on an item, in empty space within the CListCtrl, anywhere else on the dialog (by removing the first if statement); `hitTestInfo.flags` is set to 48, which, if I'm reading [this](http://dev.telnic.org/rep/apps/windows_mobile/trunk/Smartphone/DottelSP/dottel/resource.h) correctly, means "Below, and to the right of the whole CListCtrl". Which doesn't really make sense when I'm first checking if it's within the CListCtrl.

So do I have an incorrect assumption somewhere? Is my code incorrect? Am I missing something?

As a possibly-related, or maybe not, **BONUS QUESTION**, both `LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON` and `LVHT_ABOVE` are `#define`d as 0x08 - why is this? This may be key to my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think HitTest() needs a position in client coordinates. It's been a while since I last did this, but it doesn't make sense to me to pass screen coordinates into a client window hit testing routine. Add `m_itemList.ScreenToClient(&pos);` before `hitTestInfo.pt = pos;` and see if that helps.

Furthermore, note that OnContextMenu() may not be the call you're looking for. It is called in response to (by default) shift-f10 as well. The documentation of WM_CONTEXTMENU is (on reading it diagonally, I don't remember how it works from when I last did this) not very clear on what the content of 'pos' will be in that case; you may need to do an explicit `GetCursorPos()` to handle that case. Or just show your context in WM_RBUTTONDOWN.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll also look into the WM_RBUTTONDOWN thing - you're right, it is causing the context menu to appear incorrectly.

Comment: The Pos passed in to OnContextMenu will be (-1, -1) I believe, in the case of Shift-F10 or the dedicated Menu key.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with `HitTest` for list control.
It has obscure effect of returning item 0 and `LVHT_ONITEM` flag 
even if click occurs on the header. One would expect -1 for item 
index and `LVHT_NOWHERE` for a flag.
I resolved this by using `HitTest` of header control. Here is how:

```
UINT uFlags = 0;
CHeaderCtrl* pHdr = m_list.GetHeaderCtrl();
if (!pHdr) return;  // sanity
HDHITTESTINFO hitTestInfo = {0};
hitTestInfo.pt = ptClient;
int iItem = pHdr->HitTest(&hitTestInfo);
if ((iItem != -1) && ((HHT_ONHEADER | HHT_ONDIVIDER) & hitTestInfo.flags)) {
    // this is header control menu
    CWnd::OnContextMenu(pWnd, point);
}
else if (HHT_BELOW & hitTestInfo.flags) {
    CXTMenu Menu;
    // this is list view control menu
    if (Menu.LoadMenu(IDR_LIST_CONTEXT)) {
...
    }
}
```